# Ajax delete request returns 200 but error is fired instead of success

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

Hi I'm having issue figuring out where did i get this wrong, for the delete function works well however, the error was fired even though JSON response returns success.

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove-btn', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var confirmDelete = confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this User");

    formData = {
        'form_process' : 'Remove User',
        'id' : id,
    }

    if (confirmDelete) {
        $.ajax({
            type    : 'POST', 
            url     : 'library/page/process/remove_user.php', 
            data    : formData, 
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function(){
                window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                $("#loading-overlay").show();
            },
            success : function(data) {
                $("#loading-overlay").hide();
                if (!data.success) { 
                    danger ('Process Error', data.errors) 
                } else {
                    success ('Success', 'User has been removed successfully.');

                    setTimeout(function() {
                        window.location.href = window.parent.CloseDialog();
                    }, 3000);
                }
            },
            error : function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                $("#loading-overlay").hide();
                danger ('Process Error', "There is unknown error occurs. Please contact administrator for system verification") 
                console.log(xhr.status);
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                console.log(thrownError);
                console.log('There is unknown error occurs. Please contact administrator for system verification');
            }
        });
    }
})
```

And below is remove_user.php code

```
if($_POST['form_process'] == 'Remove User') {

    $training_info = $c_eta->_get_user_info($_POST['id']);

    if (count($training_info) > 0) {
        if ($c_eta->_remove_user($_POST['id'])) {
            $form_data['success'] = true;
        } else {
            $form_data['success'] = false;
            $form_data['errors'] = "Unable to remove user";
        }
        echo json_encode($form_data);
        return; 
    }
}
```

The json response is

`{"success":true}`

The user is deleted yet the message i keep getting is `"Process Error', "There is unknown error occurs. Please contact administrator for system verification"`.

I tried adding `header('Content-Type: application/json');` before `echo json_encode($form_data);` as suggested in one of the posts in here, however it does not work.

UPDATE:

Below are the logging values that was displayed in the browser console tab:

> xhr.status = 200

> xhr.responseText = 49{"success":true}

> thrownError = SyntaxError: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON at position 4 (line 2 column 3)

I am not sure where did i get wrong in the syntax error but if I changed the `datatype: text` it will go here:

```
if (!data.success) { 
    danger ('Process Error', data.errors) 
}
```

with the message `"Process Error", "Undefined"`.

UPDATE 2.0:

I figured the issue comes from the datatable where the delete button is situated at. Based on `xhr.responseText = 49{"success":true}` error i mentioned above, 49 is the id of the data to be deleted. It has appended itself to the json response. Below is my delete button code:

```
array(
    'db' => 'id',
    'dt' => 5,
    'tbl_field' => 'eta.id',
    'formatter' => function($d, $row) {
        $id = $d;
        $remove = '<a class="remove-btn" data-id="'.$id.'">' .
                '<img src="assets/img/delete.png" style="width:16px;height:16px;"></a>';
        return $remove;
})
```

Assuming the return of the $remove button results in the id being appended in the json response, I also tried changing my code as follows:

```
userDatatable.on('draw.dt', function() {
    $('#user_datatable').find('.remove-btn').remove(); 
    $('#user_datatable').find('tbody tr').each(function() {
        var id = $(this).find('td:eq(5)').text();  //row id
        var buttonHtml = '<a class="remove-btn" data-id="' + id + '"><img src="assets/img/delete.png" alt="Remove User" style="width:16px;height:16px;" title="Remove User"></a>';
        $(this).find('td:eq(5)').html(buttonHtml);
});
```

However, the id is still included in the response. Any idea?

Comment: remove return; from last in remove_user.php file

Comment: i just tried that, but still not working

Comment: You're logging `xhr.status`, `xhr.responseText` and `thrownError` to your browser console. What are the values for these when the error occurs?

Comment: *The json response is* - exactly where are you seeing this "response"?  In the browser?  Or in the php?   Could be some *other* error.  As above, what do the console.logs show you?  What does it say in the network tab of the browser?  Change to `dataType : 'text',` - if it now hits you're success: check what it is at that point (`console.log(data)`)

Comment: @rickdenhaan i have updated my description with the logging values. Hope i explained it well..

Comment: @fdomn-m I had updated the logs values in the description. Hope that clarifies things a bit. I also did as you suggested; changing the dataType to text but it goes `if (!data.success) { 
    danger ('Process Error', data.errors) 
}` here instead in the success function

Comment: If `xhr.responseText` is `49{"success":true}` (with a linebreak before it), then the SyntaxError is valid. That `49` makes your response invalid JSON. You need to find where your PHP code is echoing that. It doesn’t seem to come from the code you posted here.

Comment: *I changed the datatype: text* - yes, then you can see `data` without it being parsed by jquery - it's a diagnostic step to help find the issue.  *Obviously* data.errors then won't work as data is now a string.  You *could* do `data = JSON.parse(data)` at which point you'll get the same **this is not valid JSON** error that you're already getting

Comment: Here's what's happening:  your *processing* code is running fine - it's attempting to return JSON - somewhere along the line, this becomes **invalid JSON** - jquery receives this as a 200 and a string (as that's what JSON is, a string) - ok so far - with `dataType: 'json',`, jquery then attempts to convert the string to an object - this fails as it's not valid JSON - and you get the (fairly clear/explicit) error message telling you that there's extra characters in the JSON.

Comment: `Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON at position 4 (line 2 column 3)` - looks like your script is outputting more than you think, after the JSON. Try `exit;` after you echo the JSON, instead of return-ing to somewhere else.

Comment: @rickdenhaan I see! thanks, i noticed the id of to be deleted data i s attached in the response. I assume something to do with the way i append the id in the delete button. Apology for not including that in the description before, I have just updated the details.

Comment: @fdomn-m thanks, i figured it also including the id of the data I'm deleting into the response. Perhaps it is in the way I append the id in the delete function. I have just updated the question

Comment: @CBroe i figured its probably because the id is appended in the response in my delete button

Comment: It probably has nothing to do with your delete button at all. The `49` is output by the PHP code that runs when the button is clicked. So something in `remove_user.php` is responsible.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found the solution. I basically added

```
ob_end_clean();
flush();
```

just before

```
echo json_encode($form_data);
exit;
```

to fix the issue. Thanks everyone helping!

Comment: This is but a patch, not a solution. You should've removed the code that outputs 49

Answer (score 0):

You should send your response with all necessary headers, especially the response code.

```php
if($_POST['form_process'] == 'Remove User') {

    $training_info = $c_eta->_get_user_info($_POST['id']);

    if (count($training_info) > 0) {
        if ($c_eta->_remove_user($_POST['id'])) {
            $form_data['success'] = true;
        } else {
            $form_data['success'] = false;
            $form_data['errors'] = "Unable to remove user";
        }


        header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
        header("Content-Type: application/json"); 

        // Optionally you may decide to add CORS support
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

        echo json_encode($form_data);
        return; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I had tried adding these but the outcome is still the same. I have also updated the description, hope it will clarify better

Comment: xhr.responseText = 49{"success":true}

Your response includes non-JSON characters `49`, you'll have to find where it's coming from and remove it.

Your response should be `{"success":true}` and not `49{"success":true}`.